# C# BackColor Conditions in Bingo program

Tags: c#, if-statement, backcolor

I've created a bingo program and I having some trouble in the pattern phase here is the function I've created

```
private void win_check()
    {
        //patternoneWIN
        if (b1.BackColor = Color.White && b2.BackColor = Color.White && b3.BackColor = Color.White && b4.BackColor = Color.White && b5.BackColor = Color.White && i1.BackColor = Color.White && i5.BackColor = Color.White && n1.BackColor = Color.White && n5.BackColor = Color.White && g1.BackColor = Color.White && g5.BackColor = Color.White && o1.BackColor = Color.White && o2.BackColor = Color.White && o3.BackColor = Color.White && o4.BackColor = Color.White && o5.BackColor = Color.White)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have won!");
        }

    }
```

need help to make my program better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is an Assignment operator which Cannot be used for comparison. you should use `==` for comparing two values; hence you have to change your condition like:

```
if(b1.BackColor == Color.White && _
b2.BackColor == Color.White && _
b3.BackColor == Color.White && _ 
b4.BackColor == Color.White && _ 
b5.BackColor == Color.White && _
i1.BackColor == Color.White && _
i5.BackColor == Color.White)
{
   MessageBox.Show("You have won!");
}
```